# Changing package name is necessary?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using flutter to develop an app. I've completed the app.

I want to know, is it necessary that the package name that i've mentioed in the `build.gradle` file should actually be a domain name OWNED by me?

I mean, the package name is unique, but i don't own that domain. Will it cause any errors? Or is there something which i should know?

I tried to search on google, but could't find anything useful.

I want to publish my app on google play.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a domain that owned by you. Say, you can have a package named `com.rohan.hello` and it is completely ok even if `rohan.com` is owned by someone else.

However, you may need to consider something related to legislation. Say, if you name it `com.google.app`, then Google may sue you. But that is not related to technical things.